# Thread.sleep prevents memory leak when using a MeshPartBuilder

Tags: java, memory-leaks, libgdx, thread-sleep

I am trying to make a Model from a set tiles with libgdx's MeshPartBuilder and I noticed that when I'm generating the Model the memory usage goes up by ~200MB and doesn't come down, but when I'm doing a Thread.sleep(), It stays at a normal level.

Here is the method I call to prepare the model.

```
public void updateModel() {
    System.out.println("Updating model for chuck " + chunkUUID.toString());
    ModelBuilder mdlBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    mdlBuilder.begin();
    MeshPartBuilder meshBuilder = null;

    for(int y = 0; y < size[1]; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < size[0]; x++) {
            if(tiles[x][y] == null) {
                System.out.println(x+":"+y+" is null");
                continue;
            }
            tiles[x][y].getModel(chunkUUID.toString() + "." + x + ":" + y, this, mdlBuilder, meshBuilder, modelOffset[0] + x, modelOffset[1],
                    modelOffset[2] + y);
        }

        System.out.println(y);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250L);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    model = mdlBuilder.end();
    iModel = new ModelInstance(model);
}
```

And here is the getModel method that is called in the loop.

```
public void getModel(String partId, Chunk chunk, ModelBuilder mdlBuilder, MeshPartBuilder mshBuilder, float offsetX, float offsetY, float offsetZ) {
    int counter = 0;

    mshBuilder = mdlBuilder.part(partId+"."+counter, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, vrtxAttr, material);

    mshBuilder.rect(
            offsetX, offsetY+cornersHeight[0], offsetZ,
            offsetX, offsetY+cornersHeight[1], offsetZ+1F,
            offsetX+1F, offsetY+cornersHeight[2], offsetZ+1F,
            offsetX+1F, offsetY+cornersHeight[3], offsetZ,
            0,1,0);
}
```

Changing the material doesn't seem to help and if I reduce the sleep length to 10ms, the memory usage goes up again.

However replacing the Thread.sleep part with System.gc() helps but doesn't have the same effect (20-40MB more).

Does anyone know why this is hapenning and if there is a solution ?,

Comment: Most likely Thread.sleep allows garbage collector to free up some memory in between the loop.

Comment: @tsolakp I tried using Thread.sleep outside of those functions for a longer period of time with and without System.gc() and it doesn't change anything.